# Объясните почему функция выдаёт None

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 12
y = 21
deff = lambda *ar: print(*ar, sep=",")
print(deff(x,y))
```

Почему в лог выводится  None ?

> 12,21
>
> None

Comment: В питоне все функции возвращают None, если другого не указано. Ваш print печатает этот None. А лямбда работает как ей и положено - печатает 12,21 и возвращает None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут лябмда возвращает результат, а `print` всегда возвращает `None`.

Логичнее сделать так:

```
deff = lambda *ar: print(*ar, sep=",")
deff(x,y)
```

---

**PS.**

А чтобы повторить вашу проблему достаточно сделать:

```
print(print(*ar, sep=","))
```